# Seemingly Awkward Sentence (Why would this sound best?)

Tags: punctuation, independent-clauses

Correct Answer:
**Yet one
can hear in the music of their descendants beautiful
variations on a musical sound that has survived for
many centuries.**

Direct Quote:
**Yet one
can hear in the music of their descendants, beautiful
variations on a musical sound that has survived for
many centuries.**

This sentence is grammatically correct; however, I don't understand why it can't be "Yet one
can hear, in the music of their descendants, beautiful
variations on a musical sound that has survived for
many centuries."

Can someone explain to me why no punctuation would be the best choice despite its awkwardness?

Comment: Who says no punctuation is the best choice, and why? Your punctuated example is *much* better than the version with no punctuation.

Comment: I could also see a version with just one comma after descendants.

Comment: I think the parenthetical version isn't quite right because "in the music of their descendants" isn't completely parenthetical.  That is, you are not just hearing beautiful variations (which, by the, comes from their descendants), but rather you are hearing the variation in the descendant's music.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise and an inaccurate quote.

Comment: What false premise am I asserting? This is a quoted version of the correct answer.

Comment: My first choice would be the version with two commas, and my second choice would be the version with no commas.  The version with one comma looks strange to me, because the comma seems to be ending a parenthetical phrase but there's no comma to start the phrase; it's like having a right parenthesis without a left one.

Comment: Voted to close.  The logic in your Question is too convoluted for me to be able to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You've **misinterpreted** (not misquoted) the [source](http://www.actstudent.org/sampletest/english/eng_03.html) (**The ACT**, "Sample English Test Questions: Passage 3"). None of the variants F, G, H and J are what you give as the variant you favor, that is, the variant with **two commas**:

> Yet one can *hear**,** in the music of their descendants**,** beautiful* variations on a musical sound that has survived for many centuries.

(OP)

In the interests of brevity, I'll only display the portions of the choices F, G, H and J at issue:

> F (NO CHANGE) = "...hear in the music of their descendants, beautiful..."
>
> G = "...hear, in the music of their descendants beautiful..."
>
> H = "...hear in the music of their descendants; beautiful..."
>
> J = "...hear in the music of their descendants beautiful..."

You said that J is claimed to be the correct answer of those four choices, and it is the best choice *out of those four*, but the option you favor is not given as one of the choices. The additional option, which you favor, *would be* a better choice, but it is not available to choose.

Comment: Good answer. One of the things that people sometimes struggle with when taking standardized English tests is the absence from the available choices of what they take to be the best possible answer to the question. In my view this shortcoming does introduce a disturbing aspect of unreality to the whole endeavor—because in the real world you aren't constrained to choose the best among four options that you wouldn't use—but from the test preparer's point of view, the important thing is to have one answer that is clearly better than the others. And that goal the ACT has accomplished here.

Answer (score 0):

> Yet one can hear in the music of their descendants beautiful variations on a musical sound that has survived for many centuries.

You misquoted the original. 
[Practice ACT Questions (Eng. P3 - Qs 37-45)](http://mysite.cherokee.k12.ga.us/personal/charley_ingham/site/Subject%203%20Notes/1/ACT%20Prep/Practice%20ACT%20Questions%20(Eng.%20P3%20-%20Qs%2037-45).pdf)

As soon as I saw the version without punctuation I wanted to correct it to

*Yet one can hear in the music of their descendants, beautiful variations on a musical sound that has survived for many centuries.*

It doesn't surprise me to see that the original version agrees with me.

Comment: You know that the correct answer is the one without punctuation right? I'm misquoting it on purpose.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. The original sentence (and mine) has a single comma after 'descendants'. Your first  version has zero commas and your second version has two commas as parenthesis.

Comment: That's my version of the sentence. You should realize that the BOLDED version is the correct version of the sentence. The single comma after descendants is incorrect. You can de-rep me all you want, but I'm just asking for a reasonable explanation why no commas would serve as the best answer.

Comment: There are now two bolded versions and you have just edited the question in such a way as to make my answer out-of-date. Where have I de-repped you? There are no down-votes. I openly and honestly  voted to close according to what I believe. Who says the 'correct' answer is correct? Please give your source.